# Redirect loop with Nginx as reverse proxy and Yii

Tags: php, ssl, nginx

I've been reading another similar issues and changing some things in my Nginx configuration, but no one worked :/

When I'm trying to access to a specific page at my site, it leads me to a "redirect loop". I'm using SSL, PHP and Yii as a framework, and page isn't for login or similar.

My Nginx config is:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /usr/share/nginx/www/domain;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name www.domain.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        access_log on;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx-error_log crit;
location ~* .(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|3gp|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|flv|mp3|mid|js|css|html|htm|wml)$ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www/domain;
        expires 365d;
        }
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        client_max_body_size    10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_send_timeout   90;
        proxy_read_timeout   90;
        proxy_buffer_size    128k;
        proxy_buffers     4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
        proxy_redirect  http://www.domain.com:8080   http://www.domain.com;
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        #Redirect loop problem, next line:
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/www/domain;
        }
        location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

for non-SSL and:

```
# HTTPS server
server {
        listen 443 default ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/www.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/www.key;
        root /usr/share/nginx/www/domain;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name www.domain.com;
        access_log on;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx-error_log crit;
location ~* .(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|3gp|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|flv|mp3|mid|js|css|html|htm|wml)$ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www/domain;
        expires 365d;
        }
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        client_max_body_size    10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_send_timeout   90;
        proxy_read_timeout   90;
        proxy_buffer_size    128k;
        proxy_buffers     4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
        proxy_redirect  http://www.domain.com:8080   http://www.domain.com;
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        #Redirect loop problem, next line:
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/www/domain;
        }
        location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

for SSL. You'll see that I was trying different answers from here, without success.

Can anyone help me, please?

Best.